# PersistenceProvider not found Exception in JBOSS AS 5.1.0 GA

Tags: jboss5.x, classnotfoundexception, toplink-essentials, jpa-1.0

I am trying to deploy the product in JBOSS AS 5.1.0 GA using eclipse in Linux.

Previously it was executed successfully on tomcat 6.
While deploying I got many errors. I had solved one by one.

But now ClassNotFoundException raised due to the PersistenceProvider.

My product environment is JPA 1.0. and I am using toplink-essentials.jar, toplink-essentials-agent.jar. 
(my toplink version is 2.0)

Please see the bug decription...

`11:46:08,276 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=persistence.unit:unitName=#Entity state=Create
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
                              oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider
                     from BaseClassLoader@12bb617{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@bfa9d6{name=vfsfile:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/iportman_gpl.war/ domain=ClassLoaderDomain@16877f8{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.bootstrap.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@1837697} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@19344978[path= context=vfsmemory://3j011-idx41v-hfxjen4j-1-hfxjf9qd-2a real=vfsmemory://3j011-idx41v-hfxjen4j-1-hfxjf9qd-2a], FileHandler@22157425[path=iportman_gpl.war/WEB-INF/classes context=file:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/iportman_gpl.war/WEB-INF/classes/]`

This is the only bug showing while I am trying to deploy my project which is a WAR file.

While in execution time jboss is loading the both jars. (toplink-essentials.jar, toplink-essentials-agent.jar).
(This is also showing on error console)

`DelegatingHandler@13596360[path=iportman_gpl.war/WEB-INF/lib/toplink-essentials.jar context=file:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/iportman_gpl.war/WEB-INF/lib/toplink-essentials.jar]
DelegatingHandler@32401617[path=iportman_gpl.war/WEB-INF/lib/toplink-essentials-agent.jar context=file:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/iportman_gpl.war/WEB-INF/lib/toplink-essentials-agent.jar]`

but still it is showing the error.

When I had Google about this issue then i had seen some explanations like.. "may be it is loading two PersistenceProvider classes or jboss also loading their JPA classes".

But i had set the  parent-first="false" in my **jboss-classloading.xml**

below code is in my /WEB-INF/jboss-classloading.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
export-all="NON_EMPTY"
import-all="true"
parent-first="false">
</classloading>
```

I also declared the below code in my /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/**persistence.xml**

```
 <persistence-unit name="Entity" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
 <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Please help me to solve the problem.
I posted the same issue in JBOSS community for their help, but i did not get any response.

(For detail decription for persistence.xml and list of all jars, please see the [Jboss community link](https://community.jboss.org/message/810207))

So, Anyone help me to find out problem.
Any suggestions will be a greatly helpful to me...
Thanks in Advance..

(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Please give a suggestion. My work had completely in hold state. Please please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above issue had resloved when i removed the white spaces between the `<provider>` tag in ***persistence.xml*** as below.

`<provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>`